# How do I know when window is created?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How can I check if window is already created? I tried this

```
BOOL isWindowReady = FALSE;
while(!isWindowReady)
{
    hwnd = FindWindow(windowClass, NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        hwnd = FindWindow(windowClass, NULL);
    }
    else {
        isWindowReady = TRUE;
    }
}
```

but id doesn't work.

Comment: if hwnd is null in your function, you procceed to assign the same value to hwnd which made it null in the first place, leaving you in an infinite loop?

Comment: you can know if a window is created if `CreateWindow` returns with a valid result..

Comment: I forgot to add, it's window from some another process, so basically my program should start another process and wait until it creates another window.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is technically fine (though your second call to `FindWindow()` is redundant) - provided you are supplying the correct value for `windowClass`, that is.

That being said, your loop can be simplified:

```
while (!FindWindow(windowClass, NULL)) { Sleep(100); }
```

Or, if you need the `HWND` to access the window later:

```
HWND hWindow;
do
{
    hWindow = FindWindow(windowClass, NULL);
    if (hWindow) break;
    Sleep(100);
}
while (true);
```

Comment: I thought using Sleep function is not ok.

Comment: and btw, it still doesn't work. It works when I just add Sleep(800) between CreateProcess and FindWIndow, but I do not like this

Comment: If it is not working, then chances are that either 1) you are not using the correct `windowClass` to begin with, or 2) the window is being created and destroyed in between loop iterations so you never see it.

Comment: A better solution would be to have the OS notify you when the window is created, instead of you periodically polling for its existence. To be notified of window creations, you can use a `WH_CBT` hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx), or an `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` hook via [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx). Since you know the process that the window belongs to, you can limit the hook to just that process instead of hooking every process globally.

Comment: 1 - windowClass is correct - when I just add Sleep(800) for example between CreateProcess and FindWindow it works fine

Comment: There is NO difference between calling `FindWindow()` in a loop vs calling it one time after a long delay. `FindWindow()` has no concept of timing.  Either the window exists at the time of the call, or it does not exist.  Something else is going on to prevent your code from finding the window when calling `FindWindow()` in a loop, and the most likely culprit is that the window really does not exist at the times your loop calls `FindWindow()`. Of course, like many APIs `FindWindow()` can fail, so make sure to check `GetLastError()` like the documentation says.

Comment: Like Remy said, hooks are a better option that does not depend on timing. If you want to poll with FindWindow you have to do that repeatedly, i.e. retry until it's found (with any sleeping delay that's not too low).